# Joint CDF of M(t) and B(t), where B(t) is the standard BM and M(t) is maximum value of standard BM on [0,t]

Tags: cumulative-distribution-function, brownian-motion

We have to find - 
$F_{M(t),B(t)}(m,x) = P(M(t) \leq m, B(t) \leq x)$.

$T_{m} = inf\{t\geq 0: B(t) = m\}$.
We know that, 
$$ P(M(t) \geq m, B(t) \leq x) = P(T_{m} \leq t, B(t) \leq x)$$,

$$ = P(T_{m} \leq t, B(t) \geq 2m-x)$$
$$ = P(B(t) \geq 2m-x)$$
$$ = 1 - \Phi\Bigg(\frac{2m-x}{\sqrt{t}}\Bigg)$$

How do I go from $P(M(t) \geq m, B(t) \leq x)$ to $P(M(t) \leq m, B(t) \leq x)$?